# Can some explain the logic for this output?

Tags: c++, stl, c++14

I am printing a string (created by bitset in stl) and then printing the string directly and by using loop why there is difference in the output?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<bitset>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    const int m=16;
    int n;
    int arr[m];
        cin>>n;
        bitset<m>bt(n);
        cout<<bt<<endl;
        for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
        {
            cout<<bt[i];
        }
}
```

Input:
995

Output:
0000001111100011        //Printing string
1100011111000000     //Printing using loop

The output of one is reverse the other .
I do not understand why this is happening?

Comment: That's all because `std::bitset::to_string` returns string where first bit means highest https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/to_string

Comment: This was already answered on your previous question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/61318994/104774), I guess that was not clear enough.

Comment: Earlier i was not knowing that the index for a bit map start from rightmost bit. Therefore i was unable to understand it there. Thank you for taking out your precious time for my doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cout << bt << endl;
```

The above prints the number as desired

```
cout << bt[0] << endl;
```

however, when we index a bitmap, the indexing starts from the rightmost bit, or the LSB.

As quoted on http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/operator[]/

> Order positions are counted from the rightmost bit, which is order position 0.

Answer (score 0):

It is consistent with the way bits are usually numbered, `[0]` represents the LSB(least significant bit). When you convert bitset to string — it will contain bits the opposite order, with first character corresponding to `N-1`th bit.